# Add caption to all titles' tables in a document

Tags: vba, ms-word, title, caption

I have a Word document (with many pages and it was generated using SAS).

- The doucument containes many tables / plots.
- Every  table / plot starts in a new page (Some tables spreads to more then 1 page).
- Some tables / plots have  footnotes at their bottom.
- Every table / plot have a title that describe their  content ( like "Frequency Distribution of Sex by Treatment Group").

[image]

What I am trying to do is write a VBA code that:

1. Add caption to all titles (so it would look like "Table 1  Frequency Distribution of Sex by Treatment Group"):

   [image]
2. Change the titles font (name="Times New Roman"/ size=12/ bold=True)
3. At the bottom of every  table / plot create an empty line with style="Normal-text".

The main problem ( for now.. ) is how to select the titles, could not find way to select the first row /  para­graph in every **page** (not to mention that some tables spreads to more then 1 page).
everywhere I looked it was explained about first  row /  para­graph in a **document**.

Answer (score 0):

I think a good place to start would be to familiarize yourself with the Table object in Word.  If the tables generated by SAS are Word tables then you probably need to set up a loop to iterate through all of the tables in the document.  You can then change the attributes you described for each table within the loop.

[Table Object (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834860.aspx)